# Groovy Galapagos: "Target platforms"

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As described in ["REP 3 -- Target Platforms" document](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html):

*Groovy Galapagos (Aug 2012)*

1. *Ubuntu Oneiric*
2. *Ubuntu P*
3. *System libraries TBD*

1st question: Why Ubuntu Precise (12.04) is not in the list?

2nd question: It is supposed to be available on October instead of August, right?

**Thanks in advance for your answers!**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38782/groovy-galapagos:-%22target-platforms%22/) by [1morelearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/2840/1morelearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2012-07-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Ubuntu P *is* Precise.
2. The current [Groovy release target](http://ros.org/wiki/groovy/Planning) is October 15th.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [1morelearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/2840/1morelearner/) on 2012-07-14**:
Thank you very much Jack!  I feel kind of stupid right now about 1st question ;)

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-14**:
I don't believe the Precise Pangolin name had yet been selected when REP-003 was last updated. There should probably be a new REP-003 update soon.